# create column based on other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

earlier I had asked question in wrong way.
i have erased it completely and asking again.

[image]

suppose there are columns A ,B ,C

```
c = A > B
```

after some time, suppose value in `A2` changes to 20 now `C2` will be `true`

again after some time, suppose value in `A2` changes to 1 now `C2` will be `false`

I want to add another column D such that, whenever value in cell in column `C`
becomes `true` ,**for the first time**, **corresponding cell in** `D` i.e `D2` should be true,
and it should remain true even if value in cell `c2` in column C keep on changing
from true to false and vice versa

same for other rows

I hope I have asked this time clearly.

**edit 2:**
**actual problem**

values in this column keep on changing throughout the day,
lets say values in row number 5 and 6 was true at some point during the day

when i see this data, at  eod (end of the day) value in this rows is false

**i want to know, for which rows the value in column cr3 was true for at least once
in a day**

to solve this issue, i wanted to create another column which will contain
value as `true` for this rows, as at some point during the day they had
`true value` in them

[image]

Comment: You can use VBA: `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: So basically (starting from top) once a c3 is true, c4 has to be true?

Comment: yes, and it should remain true even if value in c3 changes to false again

Comment: @BigBen sir i have erased previous question and asked again please look

Comment: My comment remains the same. You can use VBA for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in you sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim DblRow As Double
    
    'Setting RngSource as the first data cell of the third column.
    Set RngSource = Me.Range("C1")
    
    'Resetting RngSource as the whole continuous data of the third column .
    Set RngSource = Me.Range(RngSource, RngSource.End(xlDown))
    
    'Checking if the RngSource is full.
    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(RngSource) = 0 Then
        
        'Setting RngResult as the range offset of RngSource.
        Set RngResult = RngSource.Offset(0, 1)
        
        For DblRow = 1 To RngSource.Rows.Count
            RngResult.Cells(DblRow, 1).Value = ((RngResult.Cells(DblRow, 1).Value Or RngSource.Cells(DblRow, 1).Value) = True)
        Next
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: this should work,    =OR(C5;D2)  here isnt comma should be there instead of semicolon?

Comment: Ye, sorry. Quick manual translation. Missed the comma-column switch. ^^

Comment: i think i asked a wrong question, please look at question now, i have made changes,

Comment: Ye, the new question is quite different. As BigBen said, VBA and `Worksheet_Calculate` event is the way. Try the code i've posted.

Comment: or can you please tell , how can i generate required column using the code you have written?

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference according to edit 2. My code should be able to achieve its requests already. Isn't it working?

Comment: where can i see RngResult values,  i have added this code in sheet module, how to see if its working

Comment: The code activates itself whenever the sheet is re-calculated. Try to change a value in the sheet and see if it's working. The code needs a continuous column of data in `RngSource` (a single row won't be enouth). Since you have a header in cell C1 you might change the line `Set RngSource = Me.Range("C1")` into `Set RngSource = Me.Range("C2")`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228901/discussion-between-user4599-and-evil-blue-monkey).